# Simple jQuery - name function then call it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

It's embarrassing, quite frankly, that I can't find the solution when it's certainly out there and that I can't just figure it out myself. Nonetheless...

I want to build a function and then call it if a condition has been satisfied, and when called I want to reference an element that the function then interacts with. So for example, I want to reference a div and have the function hide a bunch of divs and then show the referenced one depending on the condition satisfied. All of this happening on document ready.

I have the below, elements with class '.hero-slide' are hidden as expected but '#hero-slide-2' and '3' don't show:

```
function showHeroSlide() {
    $('.hero-slide').css({ 'display' : 'none' });
    $(this).css({ 'display' : 'block' });
}

if (bgFilename === '02.jpg') {
    showHeroSlide('#hero-slide-2');
}
else if (bgFilename === '03.jpg') {
    showHeroSlide('#hero-slide-3');
}
else {
    ... 
}
```

Comment: You're passing a parameter to the function, but the function does not pay attention to any parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function showHeroSlide(slide) {
    $('.hero-slide').css({ 'display' : 'none' });
    $(slide).css({ 'display' : 'block' });
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a function which doesn't take any params. Pass the id's #hero-slide-2 & #hero-slide-3 as parameter.

```
function showHeroSlide(elem) {
   $('.hero-slide').css({ 'display' : 'none' });
   $(elem).css({ 'display' : 'block' });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to decide based on the filename, try this:

```
function showHeroSlide(bgFileName) {
  $('.hero-slide').css({ 'display' : 'none' });
  $('#hero-slide-'+parseInt(bgFileName,10).css({ 'display' : 'block' });
}


var bgFilename = "02.jpg";
showHeroSlide(bgFilename);
```

Comment: I accepted the previous answer as it very simply resolved the issue - that I wasn't passing a parameter. Sadly I can't change the HTML, otherwise this would be a good approach.